# Can Cloudinit be used to automate complex configuration such as UFW and Apache

Tags: bash, cloud-init

Cloudinit can handle basic configuration like creating users and groups, installing packages, mount storage points, and more (see [Cloud Config Examples](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html)). But can it handle more complex tasks like the below, and if so, how? A minimal working example would be appreciated.

```
 # KNOWN: Replicating the below user creation with sudo privelges and a home                                    
 # directory is possible through cloudinit
 sudo adduser johnny
 sudo usermod -aG sudo johnny
 
 # KNOWN: Replicating the below public/private key creation is possible through
 # cloudinit
 ssh johny@10.0.0.1 "ssh-keygen -t rsa"
 
 # UNKNOWN: Is it possible to update the firewall rules in cloudinit or should
 # one simply SSH in afterwards like so
 ssh johnny@10.0.0.1 "
     sudo ufw enable
     sudo ufw allow http
     sudo ufw allow https"
 
 # UNKNOWN: Is it possible to deploy LetsEncrypt cetrificates or should one
 # simply SSH in afterwrds like so
 ssh johnny@10.0.0.1 "
     sudo service apache2 restart
     sudo certbot --apache"
 
 # UNKNOWN: Is it possible to clone and install git repositories or should one
 # simply SSH in afterwards like so
 ssh johnny@10.0.0.1 "
     GIT_NAME=johnny
     GIT_EMAIL=johnny.rico@citizen.federation
     git confing --global user.name $GIT_NAME
     git confing --global user.email $GIT_EMAIL
     git clone git@github.com:Federation:clandathu.git
     cd clandathu/install
     make --kill-em-all
     sudo make install"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring specifically to the [cloud-config](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#cloud-config-data), then all of the unknowns that you have listed don't have specific [modules](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html) for them. However, you can also run arbitrary shell scripts via the [runcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#runcmd) module, or by specifying a [script as your user data](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#user-data-script) instead of a cloud config. It just has to start with `#!` rather than `#cloud-config`. If you want both a cloud config and a custom shell script, you can build a [mime multi part archive](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#helper-subcommand-to-generate-mime-messages) with a cloud-init helper command.